# Android Notifications push php error

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i am trying to send a notification push to an user, but there is no way to complete that,

There is the code i use in php

```
    $message = new gcm(); 
    $message->sendMessageToPhone(2, $message,$valor);

    class gcm 
    { 
    function sendMessageToPhone($collapseKey, $messageText, $gcmcode)  
{           
         $apiKey = 'there is my apikey';  
         $headers = array('Authorization:key=' . $apiKey); 
         $data = array(      'registration_id' => $gcmcode,      'collapse_key' => $collapseKey,      'data.message' => $messageText);
         $ch = curl_init(); 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send"); 
         if ($headers)     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         $response = curl_exec($ch);  
         $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
         if (curl_errno($ch)) {     return 'fail';    }    
         if ($httpCode != 200) {     return 'status code 200';    }  
         curl_close($ch);   
         return $response;      
}
```

and i get that error when i execute the php

Catchable fatal error: Object of class gcm could not be converted to string in /path/gcm.php on line 25

Line 25 =     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi friend I had to develop a push notification part for some bundle on Symfony 2.x
only use the Class and change the namespaces, add you key, I hope it's help you. and i'm sorry for my bad english.

Remember that the Id of the device has to be registered in the Cloud.

from controller:

```
    /*
     * Google API Key
     */
    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // Place your Google API Key
    $gcm = new \MessageBundle\Classes\GCM();

    $message = "Hello";
$registatoin_ids = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
```

The class:

```
    <?php


/**
 * GCM
 *
 * @author Esteban lopez
 */
class GCM {


    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
       // echo $result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the constructor of gcm. Add the following lines to your php inside class gcm

```
function __construct() {

}
```